# Ggplot2 heatmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a long list of comparisons between files that I made using a double for loop (see table). I'm trying to make something that resembles the heat map image below.

As shown in the heat map, I'm needing the Comparison (*best_peaks*) column to be on the x and y axis. Also shown inside the heatmap are the rate value and intersection value, both of which are I have in the table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

| Comparison (*best_peaks*) | Intersection Value | Rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep1_R1 | 4,130 | 100 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,036 | 30.05512039 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,157 | 28.01452785 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,821 | 44.09200969 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,574 | 38.11138015 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,575 | 38.13559322 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,004 | 29.12677691 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep2_R1 | 3,447 | 100 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,053 | 30.54830287 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,582 | 45.89498114 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,392 | 40.38294169 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,393 | 40.41195242 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,143 | 27.67554479 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,064 | 30.86742095 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep3_R1 | 4,607 | 100 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,894 | 41.11135229 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,592 | 34.55611027 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,634 | 35.46776644 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,992 | 48.23244552 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,774 | 51.46504207 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep3_R1 | 2,055 | 44.6060343 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep1_R1 | 9,711 | 100 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep2_R1 | 3,157 | 43.395189 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep3_R1 | 3,136 | 46.19237001 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,759 | 42.59079903 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,613 | 46.7943139 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,758 | 38.15932277 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep1_R1 | 3,174 | 43.62886598 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep2_R1 | 7,275 | 100 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep3_R1 | 2,785 | 41.02224186 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep1_R1 | 1,691 | 40.94430993 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep2_R1 | 1,533 | 44.47345518 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB1_IP_rep3_R1 | 1,764 | 38.28955937 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep1_R1 | 3,057 | 45.02872293 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep2_R1 | 2,669 | 39.31359552 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs AB4_IP_rep3_R1 | 6,789 | 100 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_1A_R1 | 618 | 14.96368039 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_2A_R1 | 116 | 8.801213961 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_3A_R1 | 17 | 0.411622276 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_3M_R1 | 1 | 0.028296548 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_4M_R1 | 347 | 19.47250281 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_1A_R1 | 506 | 14.67943139 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_2A_R1 | 102 | 7.738998483 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_3A_R1 | 10 | 0.29010734 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_3M_R1 | 2 | 0.058021468 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_4M_R1 | 334 | 18.74298541 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_1A_R1 | 586 | 13.29702746 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_2A_R1 | 108 | 8.194233687 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_3A_R1 | 19 | 0.412415889 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_3M_R1 | 1 | 0.028296548 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_4M_R1 | 354 | 19.86531987 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_1A_R1 | 1039 | 23.57612889 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_2A_R1 | 150 | 11.38088012 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_3A_R1 | 35 | 0.360416023 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_3M_R1 | 3 | 0.084889643 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs R_Ad_4M_R1 | 599 | 33.61391695 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_1A_R1 | 950 | 21.55661448 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_2A_R1 | 161 | 12.215478 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_3A_R1 | 24 | 0.329896907 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_3M_R1 | 1 | 0.028296548 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs R_Ad_4M_R1 | 549 | 30.80808081 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_1A_R1 | 914 | 20.73973224 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_2A_R1 | 163 | 12.36722307 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_3A_R1 | 24 | 0.353513036 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_3M_R1 | 4 | 0.113186191 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs R_Ad_4M_R1 | 548 | 30.75196409 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs H1_R1 | 507 | 22.34464522 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs H2_R1 | 103 | 19.14498141 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs H3_R1 | 62 | 1.501210654 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs H4_R1 | 1128 | 27.31234867 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs K1_R1 | 262 | 19.16605706 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs K2_R1 | 44 | 2.927478377 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs K3_R1 | 41 | 0.992736077 |
| AB1_IP_rep1_R1 vs K4_R1 | 375 | 31.8336163 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs H1_R1 | 423 | 18.64257382 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs H2_R1 | 89 | 16.54275093 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs H3_R1 | 57 | 1.653611836 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs H4_R1 | 971 | 28.16942269 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs K1_R1 | 245 | 17.92245794 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs K2_R1 | 43 | 2.860944777 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs K3_R1 | 41 | 1.189440093 |
| AB1_IP_rep2_R1 vs K4_R1 | 334 | 28.35314092 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs H1_R1 | 497 | 21.90392243 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs H2_R1 | 97 | 18.02973978 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs H3_R1 | 65 | 1.410896462 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs H4_R1 | 1132 | 24.57130454 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs K1_R1 | 282 | 20.62911485 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs K2_R1 | 49 | 3.260146374 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs K3_R1 | 43 | 0.933362275 |
| AB1_IP_rep3_R1 vs K4_R1 | 398 | 33.7860781 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs H1_R1 | 846 | 37.28514764 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs H2_R1 | 132 | 24.53531599 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs H3_R1 | 107 | 1.101843271 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs H4_R1 | 2210 | 43.20625611 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs K1_R1 | 404 | 29.55376737 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs K2_R1 | 63 | 4.191616766 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs K3_R1 | 69 | 0.710534445 |
| AB4_IP_rep1_R1 vs K4_R1 | 598 | 50.76400679 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs H1_R1 | 765 | 33.71529308 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs H2_R1 | 129 | 23.97769517 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs H3_R1 | 85 | 1.16838488 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs H4_R1 | 2016 | 39.41348974 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs K1_R1 | 381 | 27.87125091 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs K2_R1 | 54 | 3.592814371 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs K3_R1 | 64 | 0.879725086 |
| AB4_IP_rep2_R1 vs K4_R1 | 571 | 48.47198642 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs H1_R1 | 707 | 31.15910093 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs H2_R1 | 134 | 24.9070632 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs H3_R1 | 76 | 1.119457947 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs H4_R1 | 1850 | 36.16813294 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs K1_R1 | 353 | 25.82297001 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs K2_R1 | 57 | 3.79241517 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs K3_R1 | 49 | 0.721755781 |
| AB4_IP_rep3_R1 vs K4_R1 | 553 | 46.94397284 |

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse); library(scales)
df1 %>%
  separate(`Comparison.(best_peaks)`, into = c("peak1", "peak2"), sep = " vs ") %>%
  mutate(label = paste(percent(Rate, accuracy = 1),
                       comma(Intersection.Value, accuracy = 1), sep = "\n")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(peak1, peak2, fill = Rate)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 2, color = "gray90", lineheight = 0.7)
```

[image]